# How to open a link in a new tab without seeing the URL in new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I've been trying many things to make this work but nothing has yet. How can I open a website in a new tab and have it not show the URL being used? I got this idea from [this website](https://sites.google.com/view/theadvancedmethod/html5/shell-shockers). The new tabs URL shows up as `about:blank`. However, I've not been able to get it to work. I'm new to Javascript so go easy on me! Thanks!!!

This is what I've tried:

```js
function NewTab() {
  window.open(
    "https://www.mywebsite.com", "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the website I was able to find the JS that opens a new tab "without" exposing the URL to the user:

```js
var urlObj = new window.URL(window.location.href);
var url = "https://tam-shellshock.franklinformulas.com"

if (url) {
  var win;
  document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {
    if (win) {
      win.focus();
    } else {
      win = window.open();
      win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
      win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
      var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.border = 'none';
      iframe.style.width = '100%';
      iframe.style.height = '100%';
      iframe.style.margin = '0';
      iframe.src = url;
      win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<a>Press here</a>
```

Comment: A working example can be found on this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tzLxm63j/